# What does "There's a strong case for doing at least a little selling" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I ran across this sentence in a book about business but I don't understand it. Does it mean "**we have to do a lot of things just to sell something small**"?

"There's a strong case for doing at least a little selling."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LDOCE](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/case#case__6) defines *case* as

> **6** a set of reasons why something should happen or be done
>
> > **case for**
> >
> > There is a **strong case** (=very good set of reasons) for getting parents more involved in the school’s activities.

Further, *a little selling* means "some (but not a lot of) selling", so your sentence,

> There's a strong case for doing at least a little selling.

can be paraphrased in this way:

> There **are very good reasons** for doing at least **some** selling.

Answer (score 1):

"There's a strong argument in favor of selling a few things, even if it's impossible to sell a lot."